# Nodemon: command not found

Tags: npm, nodemon

I am struggling to install nodemon on my node.js server. I am running the command `npm install nodemon -g` and the output is the following:

```
C:\Users\Stoffe\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon -> C:\Users\Stoffe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js

> nodemon@1.18.5 postinstall 
C:\Users\Stoffe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 
(node_modules\nodemon\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}                                                                                                                                                                                               )

+ nodemon@1.18.5
updated 1 package in 9.223s
```

But the problem is, when I do `nodemon index.js`, I get the error `bash: sudo: command not found`. I have searched around without any luck and I am yet to find a working solution. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you running windows? can you do a `where nodemon` in command promot?

Comment: I'm running windows (git bash here), the output of `where nodemon` is `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).`

Comment: don't run `nodemon` inside of git bash =_=

Comment: It doesn't work in command prompt either

Comment: did you `npm install nodemon -g` inside of git bash? install it using cmd prompt

Comment: Exactly the same output. It says that it updated, but throws a "command not found" when running it

Comment: what version of npm and node are you using?

Comment: Check the following exists : `C:\Users\{{YOURUSER}}\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.cmd`

Comment: Node: v9.8.0 | Npm: 5.6.0

Comment: It doesn't exist

Comment: I'd reinstall node.js and npm at this point, if the install said "everything was fine", although mind you `AppData` is a hidden folder

Comment: I found the `nodemon.cmd` file actually

Comment: okay so your `path` on windows doesn't include that folder, which a reinstall might fix but if it doesn't then other things could be at play

Comment: Google how to add a that folder to your `path` or reinstall ... feel free to reach out if you get stuck

Comment: Reinstall node.js/npm, https://nodejs.org/en/ it should add the  Roaming\npm folder to your path, but if it doesn't then you either need to add it manually or find whatever other issue there is

Comment: Also, if you're confused about what I mean by "path" --- it's an environment variable in windows that includes a bunch of folders with executables that are available from the command prompt, or powershell, etc.

Comment: Adding the path variable worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't install global npm modules using the `git bash` terminal
2. Reinstall node.js/npm and `npm install nodemon -g` if `where nodemon` in cmd prompt returns `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).`
3. If all else fails, ensure that the file is being downloaded and is in your `C:\Users\{{YOURUSER}}\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.cmd` folder.
4. Finally, ensure that your windows `path` environment variable has a folder set to that `\AppData\Roaming\npm` folder.
5. If all else fails, you probably have a typo or reached the max `path` environment variable limit for your operating system (i.e. 4096 characters for windows 7)